# Unable to convert from one class to another

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to programming and trying my hands on Class to class conversion using conversion operator function.

My aim is to convert a 24 hour clock to 12 hour clock using conversion operator function (I should see both 12 and 24 hour clock).

Below is my code, while trying to see the time in 12 hour format it shows garbage value.

What changes should I a make in the code to see the correct time in 12 hours format?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Time24
{
 public:
   int hrs;
   int min;
   int sec;

   void getTime()
   {
    h:
    cout<<"Enter time in hours : " ;
    cin>>hrs;
    if(hrs > 23 || hrs < 0)
    {
     cout<<"Hours cannot be greater than 23 or less than 0 "<<endl;
     goto h;
    }

    m:
    cout<<"Enter time in minutes : ";
    cin>>min;
    if(min > 59 || min < 0)
    {
     cout<<"Minutes cannot be greater than 59 or less than 0"<<endl;
     goto m;
    }

    s:
    cout<<"Enter time in seconds : ";
    cin>>sec;
    if(sec > 59 || sec < 0)
    {
     cout<<"Seconds cannot be greater than 59 or less than 0"<<endl;
     goto s;
    }
   }

   void display()
   {
    cout<<"Time in 24 hours format = "<<hrs<<":"<<min<<":"<<sec<<endl;
   }
};

class Time12
{
  public:
   int hrs;
   int min;
   int sec;

    Time12()
    {
     hrs = 0;
     min = 0;
     sec = 0;
    }
    operator Time24()
    {
     Time24 t;
     hrs = t.hrs;
     min = t.min;
     sec = t.sec;
     cout<<"In operator function"<<endl;
     cout<<"t,hrs ="<<t.hrs<<endl;
     cout<<"hrs = "<<hrs<<endl;

     if(hrs > 12)
     {
      hrs = hrs - 12;
     }

     return t;
    }

    void display()
    {
    cout<<"Time in 12 hours format = "<<hrs<<":"<<min<<":"<<sec;
    }
};


void main()
{
 clrscr();
 Time24 t2;
 Time12 t1;
 t2.getTime();
 t2.display();
 //t1=t2;
t2=t1;
 //t2 = Time24(t1);
 t1.display();
 getch();
}
```

Comment: `goto` is usually a bad idea. Use a loop instead.

Comment: If you are getting an error you should copy and paste that into the question.

Comment: `void main` ?? What is this - `int main` surely

Comment: @user0042 : it shows garbage value in the output for 12 hour format, also in the above example kindly advise what changes should I make in the code to use loops instead of goto

Comment: `min = t.min;` what should this do? What does it really?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose instead of

```
hrs = t.hrs;
min = t.min;
sec = t.sec;
```

in `Time12::operator Time24()` you mean

```
t.hrs = hrs;
t.min = min;
t.sec = sec;
```

This is why you are getting garbage. However, I don't think that function does what you want it to do anyway. It defines a conversion from `Time12` to `Time24`, which isn't even possible, as `Time12` doesn't know if it's AM or PM. What you want is a `operator Time12()` in `Time24`.